# PHP Script works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, firefox

I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple days now and I can't find a fix.

So I have a very basic php script that runs a text-to-speech command line tool and outputs an mp3 file. I wanted to create a front end for it, and here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>TTS App</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form action="ttsapp.php" method="post">
    <TEXTAREA name="text" rows="20" cols="80"></TEXTAREA><br>
    <select name="voice">
        <option value="4">English</option>
        <option value="3">French</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the PHP code

```
<?php
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
  define('ESPEAK', 'sapitts\tts.exe');
  define('LAME', 'eSpeak\command_line\lame\lame.exe');
} else {
  define('ESPEAK', '/usr/bin/espeak');
  define('LAME', '/usr/bin/lame');
}

if (!empty($_POST['voice'])) {
    $voice = $_POST['voice'];
} else {
  $voice = '4';
}
  $text = $_POST['text'];
  $filename = md5($text) . '.wav';

 $filepath =  'voicesmp3/v' . $voice . 's' . $filename;
 $filepath1 = 'voicesmp3/v' . $voice . 's' . md5($text) . '0' . '.mp3';
 $filepath2 = 'voicesmp3/v' . $voice . 's' . md5($text) . '0' . '.wav';
  $text = escapeshellarg($text);
if (!file_exists($filepath1)) {
  $cmd = ESPEAK." -v $voice -o $filepath $text && ".LAME." -q0 -b128 --vbr-new $filepath2";
    exec($cmd);
}
  header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath1));
  readfile($filepath1);
?>
```

**Here's the problem:**
Like I said in the title, this script works in Firefox, but not Chrome. I decided to investigate with Fiddler, and I found out that Firefox will only send a POST and playback the correct file, but Chrome sends a POST (which gets responded to with the correct file), and then **Chrome will send another GET request**. The script will respond again, but since there were no POST variables, they're left empty, and I get a file with no sound. What I want to happen is that the correct variables get posted, and the php script reads the correct file, not it running twice and playing back an empty file like it does currently with Chrome. I should also mention that the second GET request done by Chrome is just requesting the php file, and it's the same URL as the POST file.

I'm hosting the files on Wampserver.

I don't really know what to do to fix this. I don't see anything wrong in my code that could be contributing to the problem, so if anyone here could provide some insight as to **why** it works in one browser and not the other, and how to fix it, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me again.  At this point I could only give a walk around.

after

```
if (!file_exists($filepath1)) {
  $cmd = ESPEAK." -v $voice -o $filepath $text && ".LAME." -q0 -b128 --vbr-new $filepath2";
  exec($cmd);   
}
```

put

```
//This is to encode your mp3 file as base64     
$fileContent = 'data:video/mp3;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($filepath1));

//close the PHP tag here
?> 

<!-- From here it is pure html, point the SRC to the base64 -->
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="<?php echo $fileContent?>" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fix, really appreciate it. I'd like to get a solid understanding of what was really going on. Could you explain the reasoning you encoded it as base64?

Comment: Actually I was inspired by the html code generated.  the src of the <audio> tag accpets both url and base64 code.  So instead of returning the whole file and telling the browser to play it, I could make it render the html then point the src to something acceptable.  It works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Just did an experiment and I can replicate your scenario.

It seems it is related to whether the $filepath and $filepath1 is correct:

For example, if i key in "Test" in the textarea and select English

the $filepath1 would be: **voicemp3/v4s0cbc6611f5540bd0809a388dc95a615b0.mp3**

the $filepath would be: **voicemp3/v4sd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.wav**

If the file in $filepath1 is absent, the code will go to

```
if (!file_exists($filepath1)) {
    $cmd = ESPEAK." -v $voice -o $filepath $text && ".LAME." -q0 -b128 --vbr-new $filepath2";
    exec($cmd);
}
```

I can't really visualize what this does.  Probably creating a file as per $filepath1.  But it depends on $filepath.  If the file in $filepath is also missing, you will always find a GET request in Fiddler with 206 partial content respond.

So I suspect it could be caused by the absence of the wav / mp3 file.  It is not related to browser behavior.

------------------------------------------------Updates on 2017-03-03---------------------------------------------------

Confirmed it is a issued related to Chrome.

The reason for chrome to fire the empty GET request is the html generated after the redirection:

Chrome:

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="http://127.0.0.1/test/ttsapp.php" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
```

Firefox:

```
<video style="height: 28px; width: 66%;" controls="" autoplay=""></video>
```

Cos of the src attribute, chrome would call the URL again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've been using this script with GET requests for a while now and actually just switched to POST to create a front end for it. The script works just fine with GET requests, though. Is there an explanation as to **why** it works with GET but not POST. Also, the reason I have so many filepaths is because of some quirks in the command line tool I use; it names things in an odd way and puts a '0' behind every file name for whatever reason. This was a hacky solution I put together, but if it's causing issues then I may have to revisit it.

Comment: Also, in the back-end, all files are being created perfectly. The only problem is with chrome, it generates 2 sets of .mp3 and .wav files, which is very odd. If I look at the POST data on fiddler from chrome, and go to webview, it actually shows the player and it plays the correct file with the correct text. Then, when I go to the GET data, it shows me what I see in the web browser; it shows a file with no sound, and the time is 0:00.

Comment: Just figured out, it is related to chrome.  SESSION STATE: Aborted. for the POST

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, can you explain the steps you did to figure it out? Because I spent days debugging and got nowhere :/

Comment: I actually found it in Fiddler.  Using chrome to submit, you will see 2 responses: a POST-200, and a GET-206, right click the POST response and select "properties".  You will see the details of that response.

Comment: Hmm, I'm unable to get the same results on neither the POST nor the GET. I'm getting SESSION STATE: Done.